# Multi-variate Pseudo-random Generation?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

How can one generate pseudo-random data from a multivariate distribution?

I know for uni-variate, one generates uniform data and apply inverse CDF of the distribution. But how about the multivariate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility to generate data from a multivariate distribution is to adopt a copula framework: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)
A copula is "just" a multivariate distribution on $[0,1]^d$ with uniform margins.

By Sklar's theorem the joint distribution $H$ can then be written as
\begin{align}
H(x_1,\ldots,x_d) = C(F_1(x_1),\ldots,F_d(x_d)),
\end{align}
where $C$ is the copula and $F_1,\ldots,F_d$ are the marginal distributions of $H$.
On the other hand, any combination of univariate distributions and a copula in the above fashion yields a valid joint distribution $H$.

If you now have a pseudo-observation from $(U_1,\ldots,U_d)$ from $C$, a sample from $H$ can be generated as $(F_1^{-1}(U_1),\ldots,F_d^{-1}(U_d))$.
Here you see the similarity to the univariate case.
However, the dependence between $U_1,\ldots,U_d$ will now carry over to $(F_1^{-1}(U_1),\ldots,F_d^{-1}(U_d))$.

At this point we have reduced the general problem of generating pseudo-observations from $H$ to that of generating pseudo-observations from $C$, so you could say we didn't gain much.

However, once you can sample from $C$ you can freely choose the margins (!) meaning that you now have access to a whole family of distributions.

How to actually sample from a copula is another topic and you can find details in books (and papers) on copulas.

In R there (luckily) is the copula package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html) that has simulation algorithms for most popular copula families.

Comment: What type of object is $C$ in your first Equation? Is it a  function?

Comment: Yes, $C \colon [0,1]^d \to [0,1]$ is a distribution function with uniform margins. This works well because $F_i(x_i) \in [0,1]$, so the concatenation makes sense and for the margins $H(x_1,\infty,\ldots,\infty) = C(F_1(x_1),1,\ldots,1) = F_1(x_1)$ by the uniform margins property. Therefore the joint distribution actually has the margins you pick!

Comment: There is a related question in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3182925/25004 which I really appreciate if you could help me answering that.